# Semantic-UI UI class usage

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

What are the rules in using Semantic-ui's ui class? In the docs the ui class is not used consistently for example in defining menus

```
<div class="menu">
<div class="ui menu">
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is covered in the [Glossary](http://semantic-ui.com/introduction/glossary.html) part of the documentation:

> `ui` is a special class name used to distinguish parts of components
>   from components.
>
> For example, a [list](http://semantic-ui.com/elements/list.html) will
>   receive the class `ui list` because it has a corresponding definition,
>   however a list item, will receive just the class `item`.
>
> The ui class name helps encapsulate CSS rules by making sure all
>   'parts of a component' are defined in context to a 'whole' component.
>
> It also helps make scanning unknown code simpler. If you see `ui` you
>   know you are looking at a component.

The menu is a good demonstration of this (simplified example from documentation):

```
<div class="ui text menu">
  <div class="ui dropdown item">
    Applying
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="item">Applications</div>
      <div class="item">International Students</div>
      <div class="item">Scholarships</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The outer menu is an actual UI component, and thus has both `ui` and `menu`. However, the inner menu is actually part of another component, the dropdown, and thus doesn't have the `ui` class.